# Stormpath and saltstack

Tags: authentication, saltstack

Does anyone use stormpath to authenticate against user/password with saltstack?
Instead of creating new users and/or getting it from db, I was wondering if someone is using stormpath to get the data(authenticate user/pass) from saltstack. Is there API for this? If someone has an example, please post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Salt has a Stormpath authentication module: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/salt/auth/stormpath.py

Some docs for the latest update can be found here:

http://docs.saltstack.com/en/develop/topics/tutorials/stormpath.html